# Go logging to multiple output

Tags: logging, go

Is there a way in go language to log to multiple output in different levels?.

I want to have a program that logs to stdout in Info level and to a file in debug level with timestamp at the same time.

Like every time I code:

```
log.Debug("Entering some func")
res := func()
log.Infof("Result was: %s", res)
```

I can see the console prints:

```
Result was: Successful
```

And a file with:

```
2015-03-26T01:27:38-04:00 [DEBU]: Entering some func
2015-03-26T01:27:38-04:00 [INFO]: Result was: Successful
```

I use logrus and glog, but can't find this functionallity. Is there another package or something I can code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Go-logging](https://github.com/op/go-logging) supports different logging backends like file, syslog etc. Multiple backends can be set with different log levels per backend and logger. 
Example over [here](https://github.com/op/go-logging/blob/master/examples/example.go).

[Lumberjack](https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack) can also be used with this for writing logs to rolling files. Here is an [example](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/blob/ee4a3d13c8822fa1fc1e8e81280fbb72aceac89e/logger/logger.go#L77).

Answer (score 11):

Found this while looking for a way to log to multiple destinations.
If that is all you need and aren't worried about the log level the simplest way is to use an `io.Multiwriter`:

```
multi := io.MultiWriter(file, os.Stdout)
log.SetOutput(multi)
```

Comment: This is the best answer since it can be added to any existing code that uses the standard `log` library

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [go-logging](https://github.com/op/go-logging) library you can set up two "backends" which will write to stdout and to a file.

I'd copy some code here, but the example on the wiki does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

mw := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, logFile)
logrus.SetOutput(mw)

from here
https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus/issues/230