# how to properly capture all stdout/stderr

Tags: go, stdout, stderr

I want to capture and save to a file all the [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29)

For testing purposes I am printing only what I capture using this:

package main

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/tmp/stdout")
    stdout := new(bytes.Buffer)
    stderr := new(bytes.Buffer)

    cmd.Stdout = stdout
    cmd.Stderr = stderr

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    in := bufio.NewScanner(io.MultiReader(stdout, stderr))
    for in.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(in.Text())
    }

}
```

The **/tmp/stdout** command can be build using this code:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
        if i%3 == 0 {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "STDERR i: %d\n", i)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("STDOUT i: %d\n", i)
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

}
```

For some reason I am not been available to capture anything from the  output, If I run the `/tmp/stdout` command I get this:

```
$ /tmp/stdout 
STDOUT i: 1
STDOUT i: 2
STDERR i: 3
STDOUT i: 4
STDOUT i: 5
STDERR i: 6
STDOUT i: 7
```

I was expecting to be available to get the same output while calling it from go with the previous code, the strange thing is that if I change to command to be something like `id`, `whoami` `uname` I do get the result and can printed, therefore wondering what could be wrong.

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

Found that I have to wait the program to finish, as suggested in the comments in order to get the output, but in case I would like to get the output in realtime how could I achieve this, what could be the best way of doing it, either `io.Copy` an `os.Pipe`, etc ?

Comment: Have you actually waited the 1000 seconds for `/tmp/stdout` to finish? Note that `cmd.Wait()` will block your program until the command has finished to run.

Comment: Try using go-logging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208608/go-logging-to-multiple-output/38208892#38208892

Comment: Try to combine `os.Stdout` with `fmt.Fprintf`, to keep it simple, but if you want a more professional solution, than use logging as already suggested.

Comment: have you considered `go run main.go &> out+err.txt`? edit nvm i didnt realize you were invoking the child process from go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but in case I would like to get the output in realtime

One way to do that is to attach `os.Stdout` to `cmd.Stdout`

```
oCmd := exec.Command(bin, cmdArgs...)
oCmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
oCmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

err := oCmd.Run()
```

Then you can use a File instead with `f,_ := os.Create("file")`.

If you want to write it to both a file and to the terminal at same time, i suspect (I have not done that yet), that you need to use `io.Mutiwriters`

```
f, _ := os.Create("file")
cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I need to use gorutines, if I would like to handle without need to wait, in case I would like for example to pre parse the output instead of sending it directly to a file, something like a logger.

Comment: afaik, in go, you ll have to create a writer and do a writer of writer. cmd.Stdout->write->parser->write->os.Stdout. Regarding the goroutines, just do a `go func(done chan){}`. There are some patterns about that.